# Angular 4.0 Calendar - Show time in week view

Tags: angular, calendar

I'm using https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/ in my Angular app for showing/adding calendar events.

The app allows user to switch between the month, week and day view. The week view however shows only the dates in that week and not the time-period.

Is there a way to show the timings for each day in the week's view? This is what the week's view looks like:

```
 <mwl-calendar-week-view
      *ngSwitchCase="'week'"
      [weekStartsOn]="1"
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [events]="events"
      [refresh]="refresh"
      (dayClicked)="addEvent('Add', $event.date)"
      (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Edit', $event.event)"
      (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
      [headerTemplate]="weekHeaderTemplate"
      [excludeDays]="excludeDays">
    </mwl-calendar-week-view>
```

I cannot find anything in the documentation for displaying the time.

Comment: I guess you've asked same query on its github page then coming here for solution.

Comment: No sir, I didn't. And I cannot even find the query on it's github page as well.

Answer (score 0):

As stated the author of this library :

> The month, week or day view doesn’t meet my project requirements, but the other views do.
>
> Build your own component to replace that view, and use it in place of the one this library provides. It’s impossible to provide a calendar component that meets everyones use cases, hopefully though at least some of the day / week / month view components provided can be customised with the calendars API enough to be of some use to most projects.

for reference :
https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar

Answer (score 0):

You can change calendar header using custom-date-format provider.
for reference: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/customise-date-formats